# Heroku: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'

Tags: python, django, heroku, importerror

It pushes successfully, but it doesn't run once I go to the website. My full error is [here](https://pastebin.com/ZgBE97zg).

My Procfile is

`web: gunicorn foo.foo.wsgi:app`

My requirements.txt is

```
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
djangorestframework==3.9.2
Pillow==6.0.0
requests==2.21.0
factory_boy==2.11.1
django-filter==2.1.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
django-heroku
gunicorn
```

Answer (score 1):

can you please install

pip install gunicorn==19.9.0

Answer (score 0):

**update your settings.py**

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

thank you

Answer (score 0):

**OR**

**Open the Procfile and add the below line**

web: gunicorn projectname.wsgi --log-file -

thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a regular forum site, its a QA site - so better consolidate all your multi-part answer & put it in single place.